# Call parent window function from child window

Tags: jqgrid, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to call a function on the parent page from a popup window. I keep getting the error `Object doesn't support property or method 'GetValueFromChild'.` I believe the error is on this line in the popup window -
`window.top.opener.parent.Xrm.Page.GetValueFromChild(person);`. I tried using `window.opener.GetValueFromChild(person);` but still get the same error. Any help is much appreciated. Here's the code -

```
    //parent
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // This needs to be called from Child window
        function GetValueFromChild(person) {
            alert(person.Id);
            alert(person.Name);
            alert(person.Market);
        }    
    });


//parent - jqgrid

    colModel: [
                            {
                                name: 'Person', index: 'PersonName', width: 70, editable: true, edittype: 'button',
                                editoptions: {
                                    value: 'Select',
                                    dataEvents: [{
                                        type: 'click',
                                        fn: function (elem) {
                                            var left = (screen.width / 2) - (700 / 2);
                                            var top = (screen.height / 2) - (550 / 2);

                                            var popup = window.open("popup.htm", "popup", "resizable=1,copyhistory=0,menubar=0,width=700,height=550,left='+left+',top='+top");
                                            popup.focus();
                                        }
                                    }]
                                }
                            },
```

//popup window. this page has another jqgrid and an OK button.

```
  $('#btnOK').click(function() {
                        var person= {
                            Id: grid.jqGrid('getCell', grid.getGridParam('selrow'), 'Id'),
                            Name: grid.jqGrid('getCell', grid.getGridParam('selrow'), 'Name'),
                            Market: grid.jqGrid('getCell', grid.getGridParam('selrow'), 'Market')
                        };

                        window.top.opener.parent.Xrm.Page.GetValueFromChild(person); //Error is on this line.
                        window.close();
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GetValueFromChild` is scoped to your `ready` callback. If it doesn't need to access other scoped functions and variables then simply declare it at the top level instead. If it does need to access them, you need to create a global reference to it in your callback.

1. Declare at top level:

   ```
   // This needs to be called from Child window
   function GetValueFromChild(person) {
       alert(person.Id);
       alert(person.Name);
       alert(person.Market);
   }
   ```
2. Export from scope:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       // This needs to be called from Child window
       function GetValueFromChild(person) {
           alert(person.Id);
           alert(person.Name);
           alert(person.Market);
       }
       window.GetValueFromChild = GetValueFromChild;
   });
   ```